# After receiver a message Finding Current location of one mobile and send Back to other?

Tags: android

Hey friend i have two application one is working as a client who wants to access location of his friends and another as a server who will response and installed on friends mobile. as i press a button "Get Location" in my mobile a message is send to my friends mobile containing keyword "Get Location"
and receiver on my friends mobile receive this message and ll get the keyword if it is "Get Location" then will find the Latitude and Longitude of mobile and send it back to my cell.
i'm unable to get location. please help me.

Comment: upload your code please

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Fuse Api, it is the mixture of 'gps provider' and 'network provider' to get the most accurate location of a user.

Reference link
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html